# Is there a way to match inequalities in Python ≥ 3.10?

Tags: python, pattern-matching, python-3.10

The new structural pattern matching feature in Python 3.10 is a very welcome feature. Is there a way to match inequalities using this statement? Prototype example:

```
match a:
    case < 42:
        print('Less')
    case == 42:
        print('The answer')
    case > 42:
        print('Greater')
```

Comment: Personally I would use a simple `if elif else` statement when matching (in)equalities and not _structural patterns_.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use [guards](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#id8):

```
match a:
    case _ if a < 42:
        print('Less')
    case _ if a == 42:
        print('The answer')
    case _ if a > 42:
        print('Greater')
```

Another option, without guards, using pure pattern matching:

```
match [a < 42, a == 42]:
    case [True, False]:
        print('Less')
    case [_, True]:
        print('The answer')
    case [False, False]:
        print('Greater')
```

Comment: In the first example I'd rather just use the old if/elif which is much easier to read IMO.

Comment: For the first `case` it seems that `case [True, _]:` also works and is consistent with the pattern in your second `case`. Or you could make the second one `case [False, True]:` if you wanted to make the consistency the other way.

Comment: What's the point of the first one if it's basically just an if-elif with more steps?

Comment: @wjandrea match-case seems terribly designed :/  Should have allowed `match a: case < 42`

Comment: @minseong Well, TBF, this isn't what it's built for. It's very much *structural pattern matching*. Take a look at [this answer I wrote](/a/71151862/4518341) and how much cleaner match-case makes the parsing code.

Comment: Now that I think about it, the second one is *also* just an if-elif with more steps: `if a < 42: ... elif a == 42: ... else: ...`, since, as @Dennis said, "`case [True, _]:` also works".

Answer (score 7):

In this example, it's simpler to use good ol' if-elif, even if it means repeating the variable name.

```
if a < 42:
    print('Less')
elif a == 42:
    print('The answer')
elif a > 42:
    print('Greater')
```

---

P.S. Using an enum and comparison function like in [Thomas Sollie's answer](/a/74042224/4518341) is good for adding more structure to your program, but it seems like overkill for basic scripts and such.

Speaking of code style, avoid [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants): If all three `42`'s in your code represent the same thing, give it a name, for example:

```
the_answer = 42
if a < the_answer:
...
```

Answer (score 6):

A match-case statement inherently is designed for matching equalities (hence the word "match"). In your prototype example you could achieve this by matching with an if clause (as proposed by other answers), however now you are in essence simply matching True and False, which seems redundant.

One way other languages solve this is via comparisons using Enums:

```
from enum import Enum


class Ordering(Enum):
    LESS = 1
    EQUAL = 2
    GREATER = 3


def compare(a, b):
    if a < b:
        return Ordering.LESS
    elif a == b:
        return Ordering.EQUAL
    elif a > b:
        return Ordering.GREATER


match compare(a, 42):
    case Ordering.LESS:
        print("Less")
    case Ordering.EQUAL:
        print("The answer")
    case Ordering.GREATER:
        print("Greater")
```

Comment: Off-topic, but that enum is incomplete for other numeric types. If the numbers could be floats, they could be NaN, which never compares less, equal, or greater, only not equal. And, hypothetically, you could have a third-party type that doesn't compare less, equal, greater, **or** not equal. So I might add a `NOT_ORDERABLE` member for that or have `compare()` throw a `TypeError`.

Comment: At that point I have a hard time justifying the use of a case statement when you can simply use the `if/elif`.  It's half the lines and easier to read.

Comment: @MarcelWilson case statements are definitely not for simple comparisons. If you are using an enum like this example, it can be super useful: 
`match value: case CustomType.ThisThing: thisThingFunction(), case CustomType.ThisOtherThing: thisOtherFunction()`  - with only a few things its pretty much just a more complicated if else - with dozens of different options its cleaner and i believe faster